# Emacs run default logo window when opening a new file

Tags: emacs

when I type `emacs new.c`  it opens up the default emacs logo instead of the empty new file. I have to press enter or right click to get to the new file. How do I always start from the new file?

Answer (score 4):

You should try `(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)` in your config

Answer (score 0):

Whats your platform? What settings you have?

www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsWindowsCustomize

This might help.